# Safe pause before reboot

Tags: systemd, grub2

I have a kiosk Linux Debian computer.
This computer does not have a physical power button, nor a keyboard.
I want to allow users to stop and/or reboot this computer without corrupting the filesystem, while still being able to do it remotely  using ssh.

What I think:

- create a stop/reboot button in the graphic application
- when the button is pressed, the computer initiate a shutdown
- when the computer is ready to be powered off (every filesystems unmounted, or read-only), a message is displayed: "you can now pull the power cord, or wait 30 seconds for automatic reboot"
- when doing it remotely with ssh, the reboot is done without the need be physically present

Ideas:

- relying on a systemd feature fired once every filesystems are in a stable state. Which one?
- having the root partition read-only when the software button is pressed, so the computer can be powered down safely. But this require not so easy changes
- relying on GRUB2: poweroff and reboot initiated from the software both lead to reboot the computer with a special GRUB2 entry displaying the message and waiting for a key (and ideally when done with ssh, the regular GRUB2 entry is called, allowing for immediat boot. As for cold boot when the power come back)

If unclear, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-DEL wont cut it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could relay on GRUB timeout for allowing the user to unplug the system

In `/etc/default/grub` set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=30` for 30s timeout before booting default entry to allow the user to disconnect the power before linux boots.

While in GRUB menu waiting for the timeout the whole system is in read-only state so there shouldn't be any harm in disconnecting the power.

Grub also allows you to display a background image that for example could display a huge bold text indicating to the user that it is safe to disconnect the power.

Pros:

- Very easy to implement
- Probably will not break when upgrading the system
- Possible to easily give user instructions on what to do.
- Minimal risk of system corruption on power loss
- Standard `reboot` and `poweroff` command work like on a normal system.

Cons:

- Every boot is delayed by 30s

Comment: This is indeed a very simple method. The 30 seconds delay even with ssh and cold boot does not matter much (but another simple method avoiding that can be better).